# No firmware found for Broadcom wireless card (BCM4318) on Dell Latitude D610

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

Trying to get my `03:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)` working.  I just reformated and installed 12.04 on this old Windows XP machine, and I don't know where to get the firmware for this.

This is what I got when I typed `sudo lshw -c network`: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1041161/

Also, when I go to additional drivers in the system settings, no proprietary drivers show up.

Any help I can get on this would be Great, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the `b43` driver/firmware. You can install it from the terminal with

`sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`

And then reboot. Give it about 30 seconds or so to scan for wireless networks.

Also double-check your hardware shortcut key for wireless (usually <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on D-series Latitude) is enabled!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Why is this happening in 12.04 alone? all previous versions of ubuntu worked fine out of the box. It also worked fine when I upgraded from 11.10. But when I re installed, no wifi. apt-get wont work because I am not connected to internet. Is it possible to download a deb file and install?

Comment: Also be sure to press Fn f2 to enable wireless. I have a D610 and the aforementioned firmware update works great!

Comment: Thank you SO much @izx!  You are my savior!  Works like a charm!

Comment: yeh hard ware switches...are sooo easy to mess up again and again